# Add supplementary information to error message

Tags: java, generics, exception

I have tried to write a method that takes an error and returns it the same but with an exclamation mark added to the end of the message but there was a problem with the fact that the errors in java are immutable and because of limitations of generics its impossible to create new instance of error
by using new T(e, message) :

```
public static <T extends Throwable> T withExclamationMark(T error) {
    return new T(error.getMessage() + "!", error);
}
```

Is there any simple solution which doesnt require reflection etc?

Comment: `return`[`new Exception(cause.getMessage() + "!", cause)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-). Although this will always return an `Exception`. Is an exclamation mark at the ent really that important/useful? Sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: what's wrong with reflection?

Comment: @MauricePerry Because [reflection is generally regarded as bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644349/is-using-java-reflection-bad-practice). I agree with the chosen answer: it is always good to look for a better solution before deploying reflection.

Comment: Do you know the specific type of the exception when you invoke this method?

Comment: @Turing85 I also agree with that, but I see no other solution in this case.

Comment: Is there any way you can solve this in the proper place instead of altering a Throwable object ? Rather write out the exclamation point at the place where you log/display the error/exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html):

```
public static <T extends Throwable> T withExclamationMark(
        T error, 
        BiFunction<String, T, T> factory) {

    return factory.apply(error.getMessage() + "!", error);
}
```

Then, you can use this method as follows:

```
RuntimeException original = new RuntimeException("Message");

RuntimeException decorated = withExclamationMark(original, RuntimeException::new);

System.out.println(decorated.getMessage()); // Message!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Throwable t = new Throwable("my message");
    Throwable t2 = withExclamationMark(t);
    t2.printStackTrace();
}

public static <T extends Throwable> T withExclamationMark(T error) 
             throws Exception {
    Constructor c = error.getClass().getConstructor(String.class, 
                                        Throwable.class);
    return (T) c.newInstance(error.getMessage() + "!", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aviod reflection at all costs, you will have to pay for this. The presented solution will sacrifice precision w.r.t. the type of the `Throwable`. To append something to the message, we will wrap the given `Throwable` in an `Exception` by deploying the constructor [`Exception(String, Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-)

```
public static <T extends Throwable> Exception withExclamationMark(T t) {
    return new Excpetion(t.getMessage() + "!", t);
}
```

As I already mentioned, this method only returns instances of the class `Exception`, thus when you try to `catch` those `Exception`s, you would have to check the `cause`:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) { // let's assume you would normally catch an IOException here
    Exception cause = e.getCause();
    if ((cause != null) && (cause instanceof IOException) {
        IOException ioEx = ((IOExcpetion) cause);
        // handle excpetion
    } else {
        throw e; // or System.exit(42) or halt and catch fire or ...
    }
}
```

For a solution deploying reflection, please see [@sanit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098103/4216641). Maybe a combination of both answers could lead to a satisfying solution.